# Intersection of intervals in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I'd like to have in Python the list of the conditions to have an non empty intersection of two intervals, where their bounds are only symbolic.
For example for this input:

```
a,b,z = Symbols('a b z')
intersect([a,b],[a,b]/z)
```

the output should be the list of the conditions on z such that this intersection is non empty.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

General intersections code is implemented in [this SymPy PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12587) that could be used to do this, but it is not wired directly into Set intersections; it is used to resolve intervals in which something like `Piecewise((1, And(x<b,x>c)), (2, x<d), (0, True))` will give the different values of 1, 2 or 3. But I am not sure what you mean by `[a,b]/z`.